# Run :cwindow after :Neomake finishes

Tags: neovim, plugin-neomake, job-control

**How do I attach a callback to `:NeomakeProject` so that `:cwindow` is executed after compilation finishes?**

i.e. I'm too lazy and want everything (open the error list) to happen automatically. (currently I'm opening :cwindow with a shortcut)

`/callback` in `:help neomake` shows that `neomake#Make()` accepts a callback as third argument but this doesn't seem to be connected to my problem as it's a function, called internally by `:Neomake`

Googling for "neovim job control" shows that callbacks are set as argument to the `jobstart` function. A search for `jobstart` in the [neomake repository](https://github.com/neomake/neomake) shows that neomake sets `neomake#MakeHandler` as a callback. And the fact that this function is 98 lines long stopped my further research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Neomake runs a user autocmd called `NeomakeFinished` when it's done.](https://github.com/neomake/neomake/blob/310a86903200f343117425fd82fe61ae2c8a83d5/doc/neomake.txt#L380-L403)  It sets the context variable: `g:neomake_hook_context.file_mode`.  If it's `1` it's using the location list.

If you only want it to run when it's finished with a project:

```
autocmd User NeomakeFinished if !g:neomake_hook_context.file_mode | cwindow | endif
```

There is also an option:

> [*g:neomake_open_list*](https://github.com/neomake/neomake/blob/310a86903200f343117425fd82fe61ae2c8a83d5/doc/neomake.txt#L210-L213)
>
> This setting will open the |loclist| or |quickfix| list (depending on whether
> it is operating on a file) when adding entries. A value of 2 will preserve the
> cursor position when the |loclist| or |quickfix| window is opened. Defaults to 0.

Comment: It worked with g:neomake_open_list. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know first hand if it works with your fork but the following snippets works perfectly in real Vim:

```
augroup qf
    autocmd!

    " automatically open the location/quickfix window after :make, :grep,
    " :lvimgrep and friends if there are valid locations/errors
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost l*    lwindow
augroup END
```

Comment: Yes, it works for `:make` but not for `:Neomake`. Thank you anyway :)